# Creating a Class error - Object() takes no parameters

Tags: python

I'm learning Python from a book titled, "Python Crash Course" by Eric Matthes.

I'm creating my first Class and using the code from the book. However, when I run the code, it gives me an error, "object() takes no parameters."

Using Sublime Text - Python 2.7

I've triple checked the code from the book and I'm certain I got it accurately. I'm not sure what else I can try.

````
```

class Dog(object):
    """A simple attempt to model a dog."""

    def _init_(self, name, age):
        """Initialize name and age attributes."""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        """Simulate a dog sitting in response to a command."""
        print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")

    def roll_over(self):
        """Simulate rollign over in response to a command."""
        print(self.name.title() + " rolled over!")



my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)

print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")

```
````

The output of the code is supposed to be:
My dog's name is Willie.
My dog is 6 years old.

Instead, I'm receiving this error message in Sublime Text:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/recklessfire13/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/python_work/dog.py", line 19, in <module>
self.my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]"
```

Comment: `__init__` is spelled with two underscores on each end.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
def _init_(self, name, age):
```

with

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
```